# Getting the most recent posts from all users using Entity Framework/LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

Lets say I have a table called Posts which has UserId, DatePosted, PostText. How can I get Entity Framework to generate SQL to get me the list of the most recent post by all users.

In SQL I can do something like this (although if a user posts two posts at the same exact time this won't work but I think I can manage to filter out the edge cases in code)...

```
select * from
   Posts p,
   (select UserId, max(DatePosted) as DatePosted from Posts group by UserId) rp
   where p.UserId=rp.UserId and p.DatePosted=rp.DatePosted;
```

The SQL appears to be returning the correct posts but I can't figure out how to translate this into Entity Framework LINQ.

Comment: For the "exact same time" issue, use a rowversion column in your Posts table and just grab the max one of those. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Post> posts = db.Posts
    .GroupBy(p=>p.UserID)
    .Select(p=>p.OrderByDescending(q=>q.DatePosted).First());
```

Comment: So simple, yet so complicated. Looked at the SQL it generated, not so great -- 4 nested queries and an outer apply whatever that is. But, it worked!